# Can't SSH from AWS ubuntu instance to GoDaddy Linux Shared Hosting: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04

I have an AWS account and a GoDaddy Web Hosting Account. 
On AWS, I have an ubuntu instance `ftp-server`, and on GoDaddy I have a linux shared hosting server.
I can SSH into both servers from my work PC with Putty on Windows 7; however, I cannot SSH from one server to the other server.

When I attempt to SSH to the GoDaddy server from the AWS instance, I get the following output:

```
ubuntu@ip-###-##-##-##:~$ ssh -v -i /home/ubuntu/keys/godaddy-key.ppk user@###.###.##.##
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ###.###.##.## [###.###.##.##] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/keys/godaddy-key.ppk type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/keys/godaddy-key.ppk-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

When I attempt to SSH to the AWS Instance from the GoDaddy server, I get the following output:

```
user@############ [~]$ ssh -v -i /home/user/aws-key.ppk ubuntu@aws-domain.com
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to aws-domain.com[##.###.###.###] port 22.
debug1: connect to address ##.###.###.### port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host aws-domain.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

I suspected that it may be an issue with the AWS security group firewall; however, I have double checked and confirmed that the ip-address for the GoDaddy server is added to the outbound and inbound rules.

For reference, I'm trying to SSH from server to the other because I'm planning on building a chron script to backup the GoDaddy server to Amazon S3 using my instance as a middle man with s3fs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your instance being in a VPC or not.
If your instance is in a VPN:

1. you need to check that your Outbound rules on the Security Group have this rue:

   > All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0
2. Check in your VPC if Network ACLs are being used for the subnet your instance is associated with. Network ACLs have a requirement to open ports in Inbound and Outbound. Network ACLs are `Stateless`.

For the GoDaddy server, I would suggest you to check /etc/hosts.deny and any program like Fail2ban that is dynamically adding your (server) IP address to iptabes or jail file.